# Docker build php+nginx+pgsql in separated containers

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to make a php7+nginx+pgsql development environment in separated containers by `docker-compose`.

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
webserver:
  build: ./nginx
  ports:
    - "8888:80"
  volumes:
    - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  links:
    - php-fpm

php-fpm:
  build: ./php-fpm
  volumes:
    - /path/to/codes/:/var/www/
```

Now I'm just missing the `pgsql`.

How to add `pgsql` to the `docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to pimp it up a bit, but you can achieve this just by adding the following clause:

`db:
  image: postgres`

You'll probably want to expose some ports and mount the data stored in pg but that pretty much does it.
You can look at a more complete example here (using mysql instead of pg) - https://github.com/nezhar/wordpress-docker-compose/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Notice the link uses version 2 of docker compose, which carries slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a nice repository](https://github.com/ineat/docker-php-nginx-postgres-composer) with PHP + Nginx + PostgreSQL + Composer

You should visit it to see other configurations file for PHP, Nginx and Postgres it uses, but it's `docker-compose.yml` file is like this: (<strike>I removed composer part because it doesn't matter to your case</strike>)

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: nginx
        volumes:
            - ./.docker/conf/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - .:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - 80:80
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - php
            - db
    php:
        build: .docker
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./.docker/conf/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
            - ./.docker/conf/php/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
            - .:/var/www/html
    db:
        image: postgres:10.1
        restart: always
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
            - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        volumes:
            - ./.docker/conf/postgres/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```